# Orion context broker - Bad Input JSON Parse Error on quite long attribute value

Tags: fiware-orion

Are there any known limitations on the length of values of an attribute or a metadata value?

On setting a quite long string (>30-40k chars) at attribute value I am receiving a

```
WARNING@13:45:37  jsonRequest.cpp[225]: Bad Input (JSON Parse Error)
DEBUG@13:45:37  UpdateContextResponse.cpp[60]: destroyed
DEBUG@13:45:37  UpdateContextResponse.cpp[74]: destroyed
WARNING@13:45:37  jsonRequest.cpp[233]: Bad Input (JSON Parse Error:                 <unspecified file>(1): expected end of input)
DEBUG@13:45:37  RestService.cpp[126]: result: '{
  "errorCode" : {
    "code" : "400",
    "reasonPhrase" : "Bad Request",
    "details" : "JSON Parse Error"
  }    
}
```

version 0.25.0 (git version: a8cf800d4e9fdd7b4293a886490c40309a5bb58c)

Using this post command:

```
curl localhost:1026/v1/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type:     application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @entity1.json -v
```

and entity json 
entity1.json:http://pastebin.com/Esraq80S

Observed behavior:
On cleaned db (removed all entities) and service restarted the post is succesfull in the 1st time and fails in the following ones.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem using your pastebin file, but in my case it is working. Please have a look to the testing session at https://gist.github.com/fgalan/f407d065ca69cde5635894261a0f4adb in order to check if I'm doing something different. Note that Orion version is exactly the same as your (both version number and githash) and check that the md5sum for entity1.json corresponds with the actual file also on your side. Thanks!

Comment: Taking into account "On cleaned db (removed all entities) and service restarted the post is succesfull in the 1st time and fails in the following ones" (sorry I didn't notice in a first read), I have done another test session: https://gist.github.com/fgalan/35761cdeeb9bcb2aedf3b44983b20de5. M5DSUM is the same, DB is cleaned before starting the test and 2 updateContext are done in a row (both sucessfull).

Comment: Yes, versions or Orion and md5sum on the json file are the same. I am still observing the same behavior. I am doing the same test session (with the 2 consecutive updates on cleared entities set): https://gist.github.com/theodori/96828d16f3f740f506f13036ab740fb1 a and here is the log-output or Orion started with -fg parameter https://gist.github.com/theodori/9cac5751f528fc7ed6b43394a9ba1de9  Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe this is the key of the problem (from logs): "JSON Parse Error: <unspecified file>(1): expected end of input". It is like the parser were received a fragmented input or like the input was "cut" before it ends the work...

Comment: is there a way to debug the and output the incoming json to the parser?  might be through partial trnsmision of the json file? for these type of exception makes sense to retry 1-2 times. Seems a little bit nondeterministic. The only sequence of actions leading to the exception is 1) closing Orion 2) removing entities from mongo 3) starting orion 4)1st update successful 5) 2nd update with exception 6) consecutive updates  seem all succesful

Comment: Just upgraded to 1.1.0 (git version: d640ce9acf19af26ab649b1292df46e50aaee94e) and everything seems to working fine. many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on user report (see coments thread on the question post), upgrading to Orion 1.1.0 solves de problem.

The cause of the problem in 0.25.0 remains unknown. The changelog from 0.25.0 to 1.1.0 at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases could be carefully examined in order to find the fix, but probably it doesn't worth the time.